# Change UIGravityBehavior to a certain point in a view

Tags: swift, ios8, uidynamicanimator

I have a few images in which I´ve applied a UIGravityBehavior on so all of them just falls down to the bottom of the view.

I would like all the images to be "dragged" to a certain point in the view, like x = 160 and y= 300. The gravityDirection property does exactly what the name says, I can control the direction of the gravity but not specify a certain point.

Any ideas on how to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new SKFieldNode class to do this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/radialGravityField

```
import SpriteKit      
let gravity = SKFieldNode.radialGravityField()
gravity.strength = 10.0
gravity.position = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 300)
// add the node to your scene
```

Here's also a good example of how to roll this on your own: stackoverflow.com/a/22855948/887210

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this purely in `UIDynamicAnimator`, you could use a `UISnapBehavior`.
Try something like:

```
for myView in self.subviews as [UIView]{
var snapBehavior = UISnapBehavior(item:myView snapToPoint:myPoint);
self.animator!.addBehavior(self.snapBehavior);
}
```

Make sure you declare the variable `animator`. `myPoint` is the point you want to your pull views towards. Hope it helps :)